# On which place should you stand in a line, to get a bonus.

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Customers are going inside a store, the first customer whose birthday matches the birthday of someone that has already entered the store will get a bonus discount. Where on the line to stand to get the biggest chance to win a bonus?

Comment: What we can say for sure that the first in the line has no chance for a bonus :)

Comment: Did you try to calculate the probability that the first one, the second one and so one gets the bonus ?

Comment: This question is very poorly specified. What does "first customer" mean? What "line" are you talking about? Please clarify,

Comment: Also if you're in place number 367 or more, it's impossible to win the bonus (pigeonhole principle).

Comment: Intuitively, you don't want to be too near the front (else the chance of getting a duplicate will be too small) nor do you want to be too far back (else somebody will beat you to a match).  The expressions for the probabilities are likely to be a bit unwieldy, so I'd just compute them numerically and search for the max.

Comment: I don't know, I think dan_fulea's answer once corrected isn't that bad, and especially $\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k}$ should simplify sufficiently nicely for it to be easily compared to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use an year with $N=365$ days, every day being equally probable as a birthday for each of the customers in the line.

The $k$.th customer has a chance to get the price equal to $p_k$, say, as a matter of notation. Then $p_k$ is combinatorially obtained by 
counting the day configurations $(d_1, \dots,d_{k-1},d_k)$ with
different values on the first $(k-1)$ places, and with $d_k$ repeating
one of these $(k-1)$ places, and we divide by the number $N^k$ of all day configurations with $k$ places, so

**Corrected version, thanks [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) and [Daniel Schepler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/337888/daniel-schepler)**

$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1 &=0\ ,\\
p_2 &=\frac 1N\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{ and for }k\ge 3\\
p_k &= 
\frac 1{N^k}\cdot N(N-1)\dots(N-k+2)\cdot(k-1)
\\
&=
\left(1-\frac 1N\right)
\dots
\left(1-\frac {k-2}N\right)\cdot \frac {k-1}N\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The maximal value is in the script below obtained for $k=20$, `p(20) ~ 0.0323198575`

---

Here is numerically the list of the probabilities for the first customers:

```
sage: N = 365
sage: for k in [2..40]:
....:     pk = binomial(N, k-1)*factorial(k-1)*(k-1) / N^k
....:     print "p(%2s) ~ %.10f" % (k, pk.n())
....:     

p( 2) ~ 0.0027397260
p( 3) ~ 0.0054644399
p( 4) ~ 0.0081517466
p( 5) ~ 0.0107796612
p( 6) ~ 0.0133269099
p( 7) ~ 0.0157732194
p( 8) ~ 0.0180995893
p( 9) ~ 0.0202885415
p(10) ~ 0.0223243438
p(11) ~ 0.0241932006
p(12) ~ 0.0258834105
p(13) ~ 0.0273854864
p(14) ~ 0.0286922368
p(15) ~ 0.0297988078
p(16) ~ 0.0307026855
p(17) ~ 0.0314036600
p(18) ~ 0.0319037526
p(19) ~ 0.0322071082
p(20) ~ 0.0323198575
p(21) ~ 0.0322499516
p(22) ~ 0.0320069725
p(23) ~ 0.0316019267
p(24) ~ 0.0310470236
p(25) ~ 0.0303554461
p(26) ~ 0.0295411162
p(27) ~ 0.0286184621
p(28) ~ 0.0276021901
p(29) ~ 0.0265070651
p(30) ~ 0.0253477052
p(31) ~ 0.0241383910
p(32) ~ 0.0228928941
p(33) ~ 0.0216243263
p(34) ~ 0.0203450104
p(35) ~ 0.0190663743
p(36) ~ 0.0177988675
p(37) ~ 0.0165519018
p(38) ~ 0.0153338129
p(39) ~ 0.0141518433
p(40) ~ 0.0130121455
```

[sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code was used.

Comment: Not following.  Let's take the third in line.  For her to win, she needs numbers $1,2$ to be different (a $\frac {364}{365}$ probability).  Then she must match one of them, a $\frac 2{365}$ probability).  Thus she wins the prize with probability $\frac {364}{365}\times \frac 2{365}=0.005479452$ which is much greater than your $p(2)$.  No?

Comment: Should you be using $N^{\underline{k-1}} = (k-1)! \binom{N}{k-1}$ instead of $\binom{N}{k-1}$?

Comment: Note too that $\sum p(i)=1$ since somebody has to win, but  this is clearly not true for your numbers.

Comment: Can you clarify or correct your post?  Unless I am badly misreading the problem, the answer is pretty clearly not the second person in line.  In fact, simple calculations show that optimal is $k=20$ for which the probability is $0.032319858$.  That seems intuitively solid...as we know from the standard birthday problem, it's in the early 20's that you start to expect to see a duplicate.

Comment: With my correction, I calculated $\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k} = \frac{N-k}{N} \cdot \frac{k}{k-1}$ which is greater than 1 if and only if $k^2 < N$; so the maximum would happen at $k = \lceil \sqrt{N} \rceil = 20$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  Good argument.  I also get $k=20$ just by computing the values numerically and comparing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments (and not immediate downvotes), things were typed in train, now i am home and take a sheet of paper...